# Changing DynamoDB tables from Provisioned to On-Demand throughput at scale

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm planning to convert 22 DynamoDB tables created through Terraform from Provisioned to On-Demand throughput.

Initial tests for changing this through Terraform showed that it takes about 30 minutes per table, which is too slow and makes using our current deployment pipeline in production a no-go.

I'm trying to speed things up and these are the options I thought of:

1. Create a job that will do a single table, and spawn 22 of those to run concurrently (Jenkins setup might let 10 run at a time - no control over that). I see this as low risk, but possibly lengthy to run in production.
2. Scripting the whole thing to: convert using the cli, cleaning up resources not needed post-conversion, deleting existing Terraform state files, then doing a Terraform import of the new DynamoDB resources. Seems much riskier than 1).
3. Something else I haven't thought of...

Outstanding question: **Is the provisioned -> per-request conversion sensitive to amount of stored data?**

Looking for opinions, and/or information from folks who might have gone through a similar exercise.